# Take an existing array and brake it up by value

Tags: php, arrays, html, foreach, simplepie

I have a simplepie feed that spits out multiple feeds from each of the URL's that are loaded into a a associative array.

This associative array is used to sort the arrays alphabetically using the values.

I'm trying to use that same value sort and keep all of the arrays with the same URL or value together so that when the foreach loop runs I get one div per URL containning all the feeds from that URL for the day

```
<?php

require_once('php/autoloader.php');


$feed = new SimplePie(); // Create a new instance of SimplePie
// Load the feeds
$urls = array(
  'http://abcfamily.go.com/service/feed?id=774372' => 'abc',
  'http://animal.discovery.com/news/news.rss' => 'animalplanet',
  'http://www.insideaolvideo.com/rss.xml' => 'aolvideo',
  'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml' => 'bbcwn',
  'http://www.bing.com' => 'bing',
  'http://www.bravotv.com' => 'bravo',
  'http://www.cartoonnetwork.com' => 'cartoonnetwork',
  'http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsMain?format=xml' => 'cbsnews',
  'http://www.clicker.com/' => 'clicker',
  'http://feeds.feedburner.com/cnet/NnTv?tag=contentBody.1' => 'cnet',
  'http://www.comedycentral.com/' => 'comedycentral',
  'http://www.crackle.com/' => 'crackle',
  'http://www.cwtv.com/feed/episodes/xml' => 'cw',
  'http://disney.go.com/disneyxd/' => 'disneyxd',
  'http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml' => 'engadget',
  'http://syndication.eonline.com/syndication/feeds/rssfeeds/video/index.xml' => 'eonline',
  'http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news' => 'espn',
  'http://facebook.com' => 'facebook',
  'http://flickr.com/espn/rss/news' => 'flickr',
  'http://www.fxnetworks.com//home/tonight_rss.php' => 'fxnetworks',
  'http://www.hgtv.com/' => 'hgtv',
  'http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/rss' => 'history',
  'http://rss.hulu.com/HuluRecentlyAddedVideos?format=xml' => 'hulu',
  'http://rss.imdb.com/daily/born/' => 'imdb',
  'http://www.metacafe.com/' => 'metacafe',
  'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Monkeyseecom-NewestVideos?format=xml' => 'monkeysee',
  'http://pheedo.msnbc.msn.com/id/18424824/device/rss/' => 'msnbc',
  'http://www.nationalgeographic.com/' => 'nationalgeographic',
  'http://dvd.netflix.com/NewReleasesRSS' => 'netflix',
  'http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage' => 'newyorktimes',
  'http://www.nick.com/' => 'nickelodeon',
  'http://www.nickjr.com/' => 'nickjr',
  'http://www.pandora.com/' => 'pandora',
  'http://www.pbskids.com/' => 'pbskids',
  'http://www.photobucket.com/' => 'photobucket',
  'http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews' => 'reuters',
  'http://www.revision3.com/' => 'revision3',
  'http://www.tbs.com/' => 'tbs',
  'http://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml' => 'theverge',
  'http://www.tntdrama.com/' => 'tnt',
  'http://www.tvland.com/' => 'tvland',
  'http://www.vimeo.com/' => 'vimeo',
  'http://www.vudu.com/' => 'vudu',
  'http://feeds.wired.com/wired/index?format=xml' => 'wired',
  'http://www.xfinitytv.com/' => 'xfinitytv',
  'http://www.youtube.com/topic/4qRk91tndwg/most-popular#feed' => 'youtube',
);


$feed->set_feed_url(array_keys($urls));

$feed->enable_cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_location('cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(1800); // Set the cache time
$feed->set_item_limit(0);
$success = $feed->init(); // Initialize SimplePie
$feed->handle_content_type(); // Take care of the character encoding



?>
<?php require_once("inc/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("inc/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/header.php"); ?>

<?php




// Sort it
$feed_items = array();
$items = $feed->get_items();
$urls = array_unique($urls);


foreach ($urls as $url => $image) {
  $unset = array();
  $feed_items[$url] = array();


  foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    if ($item->get_feed()->feed_url == $url) {
      $feed_items[$url][] = $item;
      $unset[] = $i;

        }
  }


  foreach ($unset as $i) {
    unset($items[$i]);
  }
}


foreach ($feed_items as $feed_url => $items) {
  if (empty($items)) {
  ?>
    <div class="item"><a href="<?php echo $feed_url; ?>"><img src="images/boreds/<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>.png"/><p>Visit <?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?> now!</p></a></div>
  <?
    continue;
  }
  $first_item = $items[0];
  $feed = $first_item->get_feed();
  ?>

  <?php

$feedCount = 0;
  foreach ($items as $item ) {

          $feedCount++;
    ?>


      <div class="item"><strong id="amount"><?php echo $feedCount; ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><img src="images/boreds/<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>.png"/><p><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></p></a></div>
    <?php
  }
}


?>

<?php require("inc/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: This is a very badly written question. You have to make us understand your issue. What kind of format, do you have and what is expected array format? You have mentioned nothing

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code so that we can draw the logic in our brains :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this one:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://myfirstfeed','http://mysecondfeed');

foreach( $feed->get_items() as $k => $item ) {
   echo "<div id='".$k.'">";
   echo $item->get_permalink();
   echo $title   = $item->get_title();
   echo $item->get_date('j M Y, g:i a');
   echo $item->get_content();
   echo "</div>";
}
```